# Access struct inside struct fails 

Tags: c++, c

I have a struct A that is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct A
{
    CvRect B; // rect 
    int C;
    double D;
}
A;
```

...

In my main program, I grab one item of a sequence of items:

```
    A *r = (A*) cvGetSeqElem(X, i);
```

Whenever I try to access rect, I get one of the following errors:

```
    if (r.rect.width>100 && r.rect.height>100)
```

error: request for member 'rect' in 'r', which is of non-class type 'A'

or

```
    if (r->rect->width>100 && r->rect->height>100)
```

error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'CvRect'

Any idea how to access the struct CvRect->height if it is inside another struct?

Thanks!

Comment: Your declaration of `A` does not contain a member called `rect`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`r` is a pointer to `` `struct A ``, which contains a (non-pointer) member `B` (supposedly `rect`?) to a `CvRect`. So you have to write
`r->rect.width`

Comment: I think you mean `r->B.width`

Comment: @qbert: from the code example in the question detailing the error, I assume that `B` was in fact `rect`, so I chose that name...

Answer (score 1):

You combine the approaches. `r->rect.width`, for instance. `r` is a pointer, thus you should use the `->` operator. `rect` however is not a pointer, so you use `.`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `r` is a pointer. Therefore, the *direct* members of `r` must be accessed via "->", as `r->rect`.

`r->rect` (this should be `r->B`, since that's what you call it in your definition of `A)` is an *object*, not a pointer. Therefore, you would access its members with `.` So `r->rect.width`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted isn't consistently named, but I think you want something like

```
if (r->rect.width>100 && r->rect.height>100)
```

If r is a pointer you need to dereference it to get the `rect` member, but that member itself is *not* a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to access the struct CvRect->height if it is inside another struct?

```
r->B.width
```

if r is a pointer or

```
r.B.width
```

if r is a instance